# Google Sign In get Private Gender

Tags: java, android, google-signin, android-developer-api, google-developers-console

A lot of Users have Gmail but not Google+ profiles and many others have Google+ profiles but their Gender is Private. 
Is there any Non-Deprecated API to get User's Gender Information ?
I am only able to get this Information for people with Public Gender using People API.

Any help would be appreciated.﻿